# Can my UIView animation also have an interactive transition?

Tags: uiview, pinch, animatewithduration

I have a UIView animation such as :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    //properties to animate
}];
```

Is it possible to have a gesture connected to this animation so you can have an interactive transition?

For example, I have a square, when I touch it, it transitions to double it's size. However, when I pinch it, I like it to become interactively bigger or smaller depending on the pinch scale. When a user let's go and the square is 150% larger it will finish the transition else it will cancel the transition and animates back to it's previous state. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think percent-driven interactive transition is only enabled for view controller transitions right now. That's not to say that the technology is not there, it obviously is (see [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition.h), namely `startInteractiveTransition:containerViews:animation:`), but Apple has chosen not to expose this method for the time being. Right now, it is called only when performing view controller transitions (push/pop and presentation).

Answer (score 0):

There is an update since iOS 10, everything is now possible with [`UIViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator): you can make the animation interactive or automatic, or even change the parameters on the fly.